# NullPointerException in powermock when calling when method

Tags: mockito, powermock

I can't seem to mock the return of a public function call using powermock.

Can someone please help me?

The failing line is

`PowerMockito.doReturn(aa).when(B.class, B.class.getDeclaredMethod("getA"));`

specifically inside the "`when`" method

**Code:**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class PowermockTest {

    private static class A {

        private int number;

        public A(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }
    }

    private static class B {

        private int number;
        private A a;

        public B(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public A getA() {
            if (a == null) {
                a = new A(number);
            }
            return a;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testOdrService() {
        A aa = PowerMockito.mock(A.class);
        try {
            B bb = new B(3);
            PowerMockito.doReturn(aa).when(B.class, B.class.getDeclaredMethod("getA"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("Exception in test. " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

**PS:**

Changing the code to the following works but it is forcing the creation of a dummy object which i don't want

```
B bb = new B(3);
B bb1 = PowerMockito.spy(bb);
PowerMockito.doReturn(aa).when(bb1).getA();
A mockedA = bb1.getA();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PowerMockito.doReturn(aa).when(B.class, B.class.getDeclaredMethod("getA"));
```

This syntax is specifically for [mocking static methods](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.3.7/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/expectation/PowerMockitoStubber.html#when%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.reflect.Method%29), not [mocking instance methods](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.3.7/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/expectation/PowerMockitoStubber.html#when%28T,%20java.lang.reflect.Method%29) like `getA()`.

In most situations, you should not need to keep the original (spied) object. Just interact with the spy directly:

```
B bb = PowerMockito.spy(new B(3));
// work with bb as normal
PowerMockito.doReturn(aa).when(bb).getA();
A mockedA = bb.getA(); // mockedA == aa
```

Comment: quick note: the doc for the `when()` method Jeff provides is here: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/stubbing/Stubber.html#when(T).  Side note:  I'm sure the above is simplified for posting, but nothing in that appears to require PowerMockito over plain old Mockito.

Comment: @Brian You're right; I was copying the postscript as closely as possible. This works just fine with `Mockito.spy(new B(3))` and `Mockito.doReturn(aa).when(bb).getA()`.

Comment: oops, sorry - I meant that as a comment on the OP's posted code.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It is also a trend to not carefully read the documentation. Anyway, thanks for pointing out to the fact that each method is used in a different context